# [Jmeter]exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: groovy, jmeter

i have installed the latest version of jmeter using brew install jmeter

and i have installed the jmeter plugin manager too.

When i start to run the test i get the following errors.

```
2021-09-29 20:09:47,167 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_EN
2021-09-29 20:09:47,190 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading user properties from: user.properties
2021-09-29 20:09:47,190 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading system properties from: system.properties
2021-09-29 20:09:47,191 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2020 The Apache Software Foundation
2021-09-29 20:09:47,191 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Version 5.3
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=17
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.name=Mac OS X
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.arch=x86_64
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: os.version=11.2
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.awt.headless=null
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Max memory     =1073741824
2021-09-29 20:09:47,192 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Available Processors =16
2021-09-29 20:09:47,200 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Default Locale=English (EN)
2021-09-29 20:09:47,201 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (EN)
2021-09-29 20:09:47,201 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: JMeterHome=/Users/pradheep.shrinivasan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.3
2021-09-29 20:09:47,201 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: user.dir  =/Users/pradheep.shrinivasan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin
2021-09-29 20:09:47,201 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: PWD       =/Users/pradheep.shrinivasan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin
2021-09-29 20:09:47,202 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: IP: 192.168.0.18 Name: TD-C02DM3USMD6T FullName: 192.168.0.18
2021-09-29 20:09:47,507 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting LAF to: laf:com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel
2021-09-29 20:09:48,100 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties
2021-09-29 20:09:48,740 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Found cached repo
2021-09-29 20:09:48,851 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins Status: [bzm-parallel=0.11, jpgc-plugins-manager=1.6, jmeter-core=5.3, jmeter-ftp=5.3, jmeter-http=5.3, jmeter-jdbc=5.3, jmeter-jms=5.3, jmeter-junit=5.3, jmeter-java=5.3, jmeter-ldap=5.3, jmeter-mail=5.3, jmeter-mongodb=5.3, jmeter-native=5.3, jmeter-tcp=5.3, jmeter-components=5.3]
2021-09-29 20:09:48,963 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Loading file: /Users/pradheep.shrinivasan/code/vantage-streams/streams-performance-tests/streams-test-data-preloaded.jmx
2021-09-29 20:09:48,965 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/Users/pradheep.shrinivasan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin'
2021-09-29 20:09:48,965 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/pradheep.shrinivasan/code/vantage-streams/streams-performance-tests'
2021-09-29 20:09:49,106 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2021-09-29 20:09:49,113 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2021-09-29 20:09:49,115 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2021-09-29 20:09:49,116 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /Users/pradheep.shrinivasan/code/vantage-streams/streams-performance-tests/streams-test-data-preloaded.jmx
2021-09-29 20:09:49,245 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-09-29 20:09:49,246 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-09-29 20:09:49,246 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-09-29 20:09:49,246 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2021-09-29 20:09:49,246 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2021-09-29 20:09:49,246 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2021-09-29 20:09:49,401 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2021-09-29 20:09:49,401 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2021-09-29 20:09:49,401 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2021-09-29 20:09:49,402 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2021-09-29 20:09:49,481 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/pradheep.shrinivasan/code/vantage-streams/streams-performance-tests'
2021-09-29 20:09:50,512 INFO o.a.j.v.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Add JavaFX to your Java installation if you want to use renderer: org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderInBrowser
2021-09-29 20:10:01,410 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-09-29 20:10:01,410 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-09-29 20:10:01,411 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-09-29 20:10:01,411 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2021-09-29 20:10:01,411 INFO o.a.j.e.u.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2021-09-29 20:10:01,441 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2021-09-29 20:10:01,442 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting setUp thread groups
2021-09-29 20:10:01,443 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting setUp ThreadGroup: 1 : setUp streaming 
2021-09-29 20:10:01,443 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group setUp streaming.
2021-09-29 20:10:01,443 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-09-29 20:10:01,443 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-09-29 20:10:01,457 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-09-29 20:10:01,458 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Waiting for all setup thread groups to exit
2021-09-29 20:10:01,458 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: setUp streaming 1-1
2021-09-29 20:10:01,463 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = TD-C02DM3USMD6T
2021-09-29 20:10:01,466 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0
2021-09-29 20:10:01,731 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.h.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory
2021-09-29 20:10:01,733 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
2021-09-29 20:10:01,733 INFO o.a.j.u.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2021-09-29 20:10:01,736 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location:  type JKS
2021-09-29 20:10:01,736 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2021-09-29 20:10:01,736 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
2021-09-29 20:10:04,217 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: setUp streaming 1-1
2021-09-29 20:10:04,218 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[setUp streaming 1-1,6,main]
org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:884) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:623) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:314) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:257) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getScriptClass(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:336) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:181) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:216) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:940) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:572) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:874) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:499) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromDefaultImports(ResolveVisitor.java:656) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromDefaultImports(ResolveVisitor.java:619) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:498) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:461) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformVariableExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1135) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:893) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformPropertyExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1019) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:895) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1280) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:901) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:108) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:164) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1569) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitIfElse(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:120) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:41) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:164) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1569) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:138) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:111) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:66) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:294) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:106) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitMethods(ClassNode.java:1100) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1093) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:52) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1478) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:262) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.lambda$new$16(CompilationUnit.java:717) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:880) ~[groovy-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    ... 17 more
2021-09-29 20:10:04,222 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All Setup Threads have ended
2021-09-29 20:10:04,259 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: No enabled thread groups found
2021-09-29 20:10:04,259 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2021-09-29 20:10:04,260 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

I tried with jmeter 5.3 and also java 11 and java 17 but i still keep getting same error.

Comment: This should be open because it's specific to JMeter and the solution provided is also specific for JMeter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're using [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/) which was released in May 2020
2. You're using [Java 17](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/17/) which was released in September 2021

So it might be the case Groovy 3.0.5 which is also from 2020 cannot handle clases compiled with Java 17, try downgrading your JDK. The minimum version required to run JMeter 5.3 is [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)

Also [according to JMeter Best Practices you should be always using the latest stable version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.4.1 or whatever is the newest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page .

Comment: I had JMeter installed [with brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jmeter), so a `brew reinstall jmeter` resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that java version mismatch.

There were several version of java that was installed and it was conflicting one another .

So i uninstalled all the versions and then installed just a single java11 version.

Also ran the jmeter using java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar

this made sure that it was using the version of java that i was passing it but not picking it from random location.